# Pentaho Transformation settings

Tags: pentaho, etl

I would like to understand the following differences in pentaho environment

1) What is a rowset. Is just like a collecting of records from the input step or what is the exact meaning? 
I see in Transformation setting section that No of rows in rowset which is defaulted to
10000. What is the optimum value. For example if my input steps delivers 100 rows, what should be value here or if the input data set
is great than 10000 how will be  the performance.

2) Manage thread priority option: How does this work for the above scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how are you? I'll try to help with some explanations but maybe someone can improve them later.

First of all the most important thing to remember when designing a transformation is that (most of the time) all steps will run in parallel. So in that scenario how do you control the flowing rows to make sure that they are processed in the shortest time? The same two options you pointed are the keys to solve that.

**Row set size**
Every step has it's own row set. It's like a sign saying that the "*Max. allowed persons inside are 10'000*", but instead of persons there is rows. So when one step have the max allowed rows inside it locks the door and don't let rows get in until some row get out in the other side.

That's the main concept, but you may find steps working in a different way like blocking step, sort rows, memory group by, etc. They have to work different because of they functions (sort rows need to read all input to make sure it's ordered correctly).

**Manage thread priorities**
Remember that all the pentaho tranformation steps are running in parallel? And that the rowset may cause a step to lock it's doors and let no one in until it get someone out? Well, if all the steps have the same priority, that can cause a transformation to lock all the time and take too long to run, so that's where thread priority comes in. If that flag is enabled, you'll let pentaho say that a specific step should use more CPU and/or Memory to finish it's job quickly and let other rows come in.

---

Ok, with that said, **what's the best row set to use**?
A tricky question indeed. It'll depend upon how much rows you will process and how you designed your transformations (some designs may lock rows more then others). Usually I test a lot of configurations to make sure I'm running my transformation with the best performance possible.

In some cases I use 300'000 rows, 5'000'000 rows and even 500 rows. Some people (and the [official wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Performance+tuning)) don't encourage using a high row set:

> In a lot of cases a smaller row set size actually improves performance since it forces rows through all steps of a (parallel executing) transformation.

But in the end, you should test until you find a good setup. =)

I hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1914542/mrmauricioleite, so much for providing the solution to a Pentaho problem I've been struggling against for *weeks*!  I found a vital hint here, too: https://community.hitachivantara.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/view-question?ContributedContentKey=43c9cc55-7565-4965-b68d-c6c2f69fa97e&CommunityKey=e0eaa1d8-5ecc-4721-a6a7-75d4e890ee0d&tab=digestviewer

My main problem was that running my ktr file through pan.sh caused the shell to freeze on the data, and I was getting no error messages at all in my pdi.log. It would just stop after finishing a "Select Values" step. I suspected that the next step ("Merge rows (diff)") was the problem, but I could not figure out what the problemm was, nor how to fix it.

To be more specific about the solution: Right click in the Spoon GUI for your transformation (ktr file), select Properties, click on the Miscellaneous tab, and increase the number in the first field, which is labeled "Nr of rows in rowset" from 10,000 to a larger number.  I am dealing with around 33,000 records per day, so I used 50,000 to fix my "invisible hang" problem.